# Magento 2 update query with AND

Tags: magento2, query

I want to run a update query but it is not working with multiple conditions.

```
$where = ['parent_id'  => (int)$shipmentId,
                  'order_item_id' => (int)$itemId,
                 ];

        $connection->update(
        $tableName,
        array("status" => 'requested'),
        $where
        );
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$where = [
    'parent_id = ?'  => (int)$shipmentId,
    'order_item_id = ?' => (int)$itemId,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this

```
$where = ['parent_id'  => (int)$shipmentId,
          'order_item_id' => (int)$itemId,
         ];
```

with:

```
$where = ['parent_id'  => (int)$shipmentId,
          'order_item_id' => (int)$itemId
         ];
```

Comment: I have tried both

Comment: These options are identical...